# Node JS memory management on ARM single board

Tags: node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, sharp

I am using sharp image processing module to resize the image and render it on UI.

```
app.get('/api/preview-small/:filename',(req,res)=>{
    let filename = req.params.filename;


    sharp('files/' + filename)
        .resize(200, 200, {
            fit: sharp.fit.inside,
            withoutEnlargement: true
        })
        .toFormat('jpeg')
        .toBuffer()
        .then(function(outputBuffer) {
            res.writeHead('200',{"Content-Type":"image/jpeg"});
            res.write(outputBuffer);
            res.end();
        });

});
```

I am running above code on a single board computer Rock64 with 1 GB ram. When I run a Linux `htop` command and monitor the memory utilization, I could see the memory usage is adding up exponentially from 10% to 60% after every call to the nodejs app and it never comes down.

**CPU USAGE**
[image]

[image: CPU Usage]

Though it does not give any issue running the application, my only concern is memory usage does not come down, even when the app is not running and I am not sure if this will crash the application eventually if this application runs continuously.

or if I move a similar code snippet to the cloud will it keep occupying memory even when it's not running?

Anyone who is using sharp module facing the similar issue or is this a known issue with node.js. Do we have a way to flush out/clear out the memory or will node do garbage collection?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if your sharp library has native code and isn't doing appropriate cleanup of its own memory.  Node will do its own garbage collection if you're not keeping references to the images.  But, you can't see its garbage collection from htop command because the memory may be free internal to node.js, but not returned to the OS.  You can use a heap snapshot inside of node.js to see if the allocated memory inside of node.js is steadily climbing or not.

Comment: I am not sure how sharp manages the memory but from my code, I am not keeping any reference to the image. Also, I will try out heap snapshot inside node.js. Thank You. i will update what i find

Answer (score 1):

sharp has some memory debugging stuff built in:

http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api-utility/#cache

You can control the libvips cache, and get stats about resource usage.

The node version has a very strong effect on memory behaviour. This has been discussed a lot on the sharp issue tracker, see for example:

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/429

Or perhaps:

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/778

Comment: Sure I will try this, i observed that, if I run the same code in raspberry pi it does memory management properly but somehow in rock64 it's not cleaning the memory.

Comment: Different node versions on the two machines, I would guess.